# Not able to filter on log message in kibana but able to see the logs

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I am using filebeat, elasticsearch, kibana to ship and view logs on ec2.

all the three services are working fine and I am able to see the logs on kibana.

[image]

But when i try to search in these logs, the result is not displayed.

[image]

As we can see in the previous screenshot we have "WARNING" keyword but when I am searching it, it is not displayed.

Also the full json look like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for `message: *exists*`. Without the wildcards the string needs to do an exact match.

Comment: Actually I solved this using correct indexing and now I am able to search.